# How to convert embeded object id to string in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My message model is

```
    owner: Object Id, ref User
    recipient: Object Id, ref User
    message: String
    read: boolean, default false,
    created: datetime
```

I need to fetch the last messages in each conversation. I found some helpful code:

```
Message.aggregate(
    {$match:{$or:[{"owner":req.user._id},{"recipient":req.user._id}]}},
    {$sort:{created:-1}},
    {
        $group:{"_id":{
        "last_message_between":{
            $cond:[
                {
                    $gt:[
                    {$substr:["$recipient",0,1]},
                    {$substr:["$owner",0,1]}]
                },
                {$concat:["$recipient"," and ","$owner"]},
                {$concat:["$owner"," and ","$recipient"]}
            ]
        }
        },"message":{$first:"$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    function(err, res)
    {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(res);
        res.end();
    }
  )
```

but the problem is my refs are objectIds not strings, so the above code won't work. I tried to convert the refs with toString but no luck. How can I convert my object refs to string so that I can implement the above logic? Or is there a better way?

Comment: The [`ObjectId.toString()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/) does not work for you?

Comment: If I write `$recipient.toString()`, I get `$recipient is not defined`

Comment: As far as I know you can't convert an ObjectId to String inside the aggregation pipeline. However, you may do it with map-reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you can't convert an ObjectId to String inside the aggregation pipeline. Nevertheless, It's still possible to solve your problem using the aggregation pipeline (and without changing your data schema), but the solution is quite ugly and most certainly lacks performance...

## Ugly Aggregation

```
db.msg.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        $or: [
            {"owner": ObjectId("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")},
            {"recipient": ObjectId("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")}
        ]
    }},

    // the next section objective is to create a unique conversation identifier

    {$group:{
        _id :"$_id",
        message: {"$last": "$message"},
        created: {"$last": "$created"},
        ownerArr: {"$push": "$owner"},
        recipientArr: {"$push": "$recipient"},
    }},
    {$project:{
        _id: 1,
        message: 1,
        created: 1,
        conversationId: {"$setUnion": ["$ownerArr", "$recipientArr"]}
    }},
    {$unwind: "$conversationId"},
    {$sort: {"conversationId": 1}},
    {$group:{
        _id: "$_id",
        conversationId: {"$push": "$conversationId"},
        message: {"$last": "$message"},
        created: {"$last": "$created"}
    }},

    // end of conversationId section

    // the solution is now trivial

    {$sort: {"created": 1}},
    {$group:{
        _id: "$conversationId",
        lastMessageId: {"$last": "$_id"},
        lastMessage: {"$last": "$message"},
        lastCreated: {"$last": "$created"}
    }}
])
```

## Test case

```
> db.msg.find().toArray()
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c4944645f0a14b5b3f5b9d"),
        "owner" : ObjectId("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"),
        "recipient" : ObjectId("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        "message" : "qwerty",
        "created" : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c4944a45f0a14b5b3f5b9e"),
        "owner" : ObjectId("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        "recipient" : ObjectId("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"),
        "message" : "qwerty",
        "created" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c4944d45f0a14b5b3f5b9f"),
        "owner" : ObjectId("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        "recipient" : ObjectId("cccccccccccccccccccccccc"),
        "message" : "qwerty",
        "created" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c4945145f0a14b5b3f5ba0"),
        "owner" : ObjectId("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"),
        "recipient" : ObjectId("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
        "message" : "qwerty",
        "created" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c4945f45f0a14b5b3f5ba1"),
        "owner" : ObjectId("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"),
        "recipient" : ObjectId("cccccccccccccccccccccccc"),
        "message" : "qwerty",
        "created" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    }
]
```

## Result

```
{ "_id" : [ ObjectId("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"), ObjectId("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb") ], "lastMessageId" : ObjectId("56c4944a45f0a14b5b3f5b9e"), "lastMessage" : "qwerty", "lastCreated" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : [ ObjectId("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"), ObjectId("cccccccccccccccccccccccc") ], "lastMessageId" : ObjectId("56c4945f45f0a14b5b3f5ba1"), "lastMessage" : "qwerty", "lastCreated" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
```